# Which event I should use here?

Tags: c#, events, devexpress, cell, gridcontrol

I have a devexpress.XtraVerticalGrid.VGridControl, I have two columns on this grid. Column1 is a string column while column2 is a column to display decimal numbers. Column2 is editable. Is there a way when I input something in column2, then I tab out, the number in current row and column2 can be formatted according to the value in the same row and column1? Is there such an event I can use when tab out of the cell? I have a function to do the formatting so formatting is not a problem.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check and use rowediting event of that grid.